# How to create light falloff in Shading Tab?

Tags: lighting, shader-nodes, emission

I've been trying to make a light falloff as a material. For example, imagine a glowing traffic light, where the margins are darker than the rest. Or take  the rendering shown below, where the ceiling lamps have this vignette-like effect.

I know there's a light falloff node, but this only affects the emitting light and not the material itself.[image]

Comment: Hello, if you are talking about the gradient, use a glass material with a high roughness?

Comment: How exactly do you want to build it? A light object behind a glass/translucent object or is the lamp mesh object itself the light with an emissive material?

Comment: It's suppossed to be a single plane with an emissive material. So no glass or anything similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the lights you show you could use a *Texture > Gradient Texture* (in *Spherical* mode), use the Object output of the *Texture Coordinate* in order to center the gradient:

[image]

Comment: thanks! That nailed it.